# how to fix potentially infected binary files?

Tags: ubuntu, security, software-installation, binary

when I installed the updates on my computer (Ubuntu 14.04), I typed the password, thinking that it was asked for regular updating , but when I noticed some strange behavior and crash at this moment, I suspected the malicious activity. 
I checked if there were some modified files

```
find /sbin -mtime -1
```

and it showed me :

> /sbin
>
> /sbin/ldconfig.real
>
> /sbin/ldconfig

I checked then for rootkits with :

```
chkrootkit | grep INFECTED
```

and it showed nothing

Nevertheless I worry about `ldconfig` `ldconfig.real` files, and so **I'm looking for the methods to update them in such a way that last changes (possible malicious activity)  will be deleted .** 
when I try to reinstall `ldconfig` , I have this error while removing with `apt-get`

> E: Unable to locate package ldconfig

Comment: It does not seem malicious, some updates ask for passwords and those files do exist.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro yes but there were some warnings after I typed a password and Ubuntu crash just right after it, so it gave me idea about malicious activity

Comment: Hard to tell without reading the warnings. Do you usually have random lock ups? Temperature? Disk errors?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, No I don't ! it's the first time the crash like this occurred with me, so that's why I'm trying to figure out what happened and how I can fix it

Comment: Could be anything, try to read /var/log/messages and /var/log/syslog for clues. hint: with a crash, they may be corrupted, do no panic if they a couple of lines with random garbage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both files come from `libc-bin`

```
$ dpkg -S /sbin/ldconfig{,.real}
libc-bin: /sbin/ldconfig
libc-bin: /sbin/ldconfig.real
```

So you could reinstall with:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libc-bin
```

But if something that fundamental as libc is really infected, you're not going to be able to remove it from a live system. It could trivially monkey-patch anything linking to it to just reinfect your computer. You could probably chroot-mount it from a LiveCD and reinstall everything... Or just reinstall from scratch and copy your (checked and sanitised) data over.

But are you really infected in the first place? I don't know why you think you are. There have been libc patches recently (they are usually fairly frequent IME) so I'm not sure what you're seeing is anything but standard stuff.

---

I really think you're unnecessarily bridging what is more likely to be a bad update, random bug, a service that reloaded onto a new version of libc, etc into a disaster scenario. Especially when we're talking about "some warnings" without knowing what they were. Warnings happen all the time.

You only have a few options:

- Audit the files from a safe environment (ie a Live CD/USB). If yours claim to be the same version as [the originals](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc-bin) but their `md5sum` (or `sha256sum`, however paranoid you want to be) differ, you have a problem.
- Assume disaster and reinstall.
- Take the blue pill, the story ends, you wake up in your bed and believe whatever you want to believe. Ignorance is bliss, right?

Comment: thanks @Oli, so as I said, there were some warnings after I typed a password and Ubuntu's crash just right after it, so it gave me idea about malicious activity. and when I verified I've seen these two files modified. I don't know how to make sure that there is no real danger, I used two methods `find` and `chkrootkit` and the first one gave  `ldconfig` files as a result, so I worked around it now

Comment: Your find command is just telling you that files have changed. This isn't strange. This is what package upgrades do.

Comment: thanks a lot @Oli! the last option is the best one, but the first one is more suitable for someone paranoid like me! ;)